# If a module provides a class, why might that class need a constructor with @Inject?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Getting error

> Could not find a suitable constructor in Foo.java. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annoted with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.

I get this error when I add to class `Bar`

```
// constructor
@Inject
Bar(Foo foo) { /* ... */ }
```

Formerly, `Bar` was a no-arg constructor without @Inject. This worked (the server could start up).

All along I have a *Module.java class that @Provides a copy of Foo.

I haven't simply added an @Inject to Foo because Foo has two constructors. My Module class's @Provides method uses either.

So it's unclear to me why I need to add @Inject to this class that's already being provided. The Injector should be able to instantiate it from the @Provides method without relying on Foo's constructors, no?

Answer (score 1):

Things were not as they appeared.

My @Provides method returned an `Optional<Foo>`. To the compiler and runtime, this is of course quite different. Solved by having `Bar` accept `Optional<Foo>`.